# How to mount ext4 partition with root and with user write on FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, mount, fstab

How to mount ext4 partition with root and with user write on freebsd ?
What write in the /etc/fstab file ?
I has read many doc but without response.
What I have to use, **ext2fs** ? or **fusefs**
Please

example with ext2fs but in root:

[image: ext2fs in root]

Comment: I think there exist only *read-only* implementations of `ext4` on FreeBSD, see https://superuser.com/a/720350/65618. So it doesn't seem that it's possible to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

My user is **sysc4ll**, so, after mount the partition in **/mnt/data/** :

```
chown sysc4ll:sysc4ll /mnt/data/
```

This command solves my problem.